# Loading Combo Box from a table column name that are numbers only

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, combobox

I have a table whose column names are number only.
Now I need to populate one combo box from that table depending on  the selected value of anothe comcbo box named "cboStandard" but it is triggering error that **"Child list for field 2 cannot be created".**
NB: The table column name are determined from the value selected in the cboStandard combo box
Below is my code to populate the combo box:

```
Dim Series As String = (cboStandard.Text).Substring((cboStandard.Text).IndexOf(" ") + 1, 3)
If Not Series.Contains("Sys") Then
    Dim getWeights As String = "Select [" & Series & "] from StandardChicken where [" & Series & "] > 0 "
    loadcombo(getWeights, cboStandardWeights, Series)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt = ret.LoadDataTable2(getWeights)
    If Not (dt.Rows.Count = 0) Then
        cboStandardWeights.DataSource = dt
        cboStandardWeights.DisplayMember = Series
        cboStandardWeights.ValueMember = Series
        cboStandardWeights.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems

    ElseIf dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        cboStandardWeights.Text = ""
        cboStandardWeights.DataSource = dt
        cboStandardWeights.ValueMember = Series
        cboStandardWeights.DisplayMember = Series
        cboStandardWeights.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
    End If
```

Comment: I am confused. You call `loadcombo`. What is in `loadcombo`? It seems you load your combo box in the method you have shown. How about the code in `ret.LoadDataTable2`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
private sub comboBox1_EditvalueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comboBox1.EditValueChanged
  dim myValue = CInt(comboBox1.EditValue)
  if myValue = 1 then
    'populate comboBox2
  else if myValue = 2
    'populate comboBox2 with other stuff
  end if
end sub
```

much easier. You can do whatever you want inside, you can even hide and show the second comboBox